# How to vertically center-align a new TV to a pre-existing wall-mount

Tags: mounting, television

I'm replacing an old TV with a new one and I want to wall-mount it using the old mount.
In the new TV, the location of the VESA fitting isn't exactly where it is in the old one.
I'm using the Barkan E30 mount, and it looks like it the beams can be fitted into the wall plate in three positions. I can't figure out from the schematics where exactly should they be screwed so it's vertically aligned relative to the wall plate that's already wall-mounted.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the dimensions marked in questions marks below the schematic:

[image]

This is the existing mount:

[image]

Old TV:

[image]

TV models:

- Old - LG 37ld460
- New - LG OLED48C1

Comment: Showing the old TV doesn't help us help you figure out where the mounting holes are. If it's truly a VESA mount, then the spacing of the holes on the new TV should be very standard. Move the adjustable bits of the mount around until they line up with the holes on the new TV. Do note that if the back of the new TV is curved, your old mount may not fit if it wasn't designed for a curved TV.

Comment: @FreeMan to clarify, the mounting holes may align in more than one way with the new TV. I'm trying to figure how to calculate which exact mounting holes to use so the new TV is vertically middle aligned with the pre-installed wall plate

Comment: I would use a tape measure and measure the opening, bracket position in the opening, bracket hole locations, size of TV and hole locations on the back of the TV. Then draw this out on a piece of paper and work out the dimensions. You could even use a large piece of grid lined paper to get things into proportional scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the vertical brackets have only one mount point on the horizontal bar:

1. Put the vertical mounting brackets onto the horizontal bar on the wall.
2. Put a piece of tape on each vertical bracket at the center of the horizontal bar.
3. Measure the TV to identify its vertical mid point.
4. Line up the tape marks on the brackets with the mid point on the TV.
5. Attach the brackets to the TV so the mid point marks line up as close as possible.
6. Hang TV on wall.

If the vertical brackets can mount on the horizontal in more than one location:

1. Put the horizontal attachment point at the vertical mid point.
2. Line up the vertical mid point of the brackets as close as possible to the vertical mid point of the TV and attach to the TV
3. Hang TV on wall.

Comment: Simple, practical and elegant! I love it. Thanks so much